# Passing parameters to DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, parameter-passing, calling-convention

I am implementing a global mouse hook and got stuck at passing parameters to the DLL. Could you help me out?

This is the host application function to start the hook:

```
function TMainForm.StartHook(LockDirection: byte): boolean;
type
  TStartHook = function(AppHandle: HWND; LockDir: byte): Byte;
var
  StartHookProc: TStartHook;
  SHresult: Byte;
  i:integer;
  LibPath: string;
begin
  LibPath:=ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'hooklib.dll';
  HookInfo.LibHandle := LoadLibrary(pwidechar(LibPath));

  @StartHookProc := GetProcAddress(HookInfo.LibHandle, 'StartHookProc');
  if @StartHookProc = nil then begin
    Showmessage('Exit #1');
    Exit;
  end;

  SHresult := StartHookProc(Handle, LockDirection);
end;
```

And this is the DLL-side function of `StartHookProc`

```
function StartHookProc(AppHandle: HWND; LockDir: byte): Byte; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Hooked then
  begin
    Result := 1;
    Exit;
  end;

  HookHandle:= SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, @MouseHookProc, hInstance, 0);
...
end;
```

I think that what I am trying to do is clear - simply pass the LockDirection param to the dll so I can process the mouse messages accordingly. However, when I pass 0 as the param, on the dll-side it shows 'ě'(236). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Minor comment. I think it is more idiomatic to use `PChar` rather than `PWideChar` when calling Windows API functions. If you use `PChar` then the code will compile correctly on all versions of Delphi. Of course, if you had been calling `LoadLibraryW`, and `LibPath` was a `WideString` or `UnicodeString`, then `PWideChar` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TStartHook` is declared incorrectly. It is missing the calling convention. It should be:

```
type
  TStartHook = function(AppHandle: HWND; LockDir: byte): Byte; stdcall;
```

Comment: Oh. This fixed it. Out of curiosity - if I was to delete both `stdcall;` conventions, it would work too, but only if both parts were compiled in delphi?

Comment: That is correct. With no calling convention the default is the `register` convention which is private to Delphi. In principle this convention could change from one Delphi version to the next, but I believe it never has. On x64 Windows it is all irrelevant because there is only one calling convention.